# QT on raspberry pi 3 model b running ubuntu mate 5.10

Tags: qt, ubuntu, raspberry-pi3, mate

I am a noob trying to run QT creator on my raspberry pi 3 model b With the ubuntu mate 15.1. I followed instructions online for installing QT and it ran the installation prosess. But when I try to run creator it Only opens the program gui toolbars. The Main window never opens And after about 2 minutes IT shots down. Does anybody know why? Or does anybody have a working setup?

Bjørn